# Angular 2 and Primeng : ui-state not working since i updated to Primeng 2.0

Tags: primeng, angular

Since ip assed to primeng 2.0 release, some primeng component styles don't work and ui-state classes (ui-state-hover, ui-state-disabled, etc) too.
And it works in primeng 1.0.
I'm actually in Angular 4 and primeng 4 RC1, but the problem still remain.
Thank you.

Comment: It is documented at CSS over JS section;

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-2-0-rc1-released/

So :hover and :disabled are used for styling native elements.

Comment: It seems to be that, thank you !

Comment: @CagatayCivici Just one question, I am trying to apply the disabled state to pButton (with [disabled]="true") the way it looked like in PrimeNG 1. My button is disabled, as in "it can't be clicked", but it and the mouse behave and look as if it was active.
How would I do this in v4? Can I see an example somewhere? Even from the PrimeNG website I cannot deduce how this would be done... Thanks!

Comment: OK, never mind. We were using PrimeUI themes. They are outdated now, only the themes included in PrimeNG are compatible.